# Remotely connecting to a MySQL database using PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

here i am trying to connect to MySQL database using `PHP-PDO` from remote server using IP address. when put ip address in place of host it gives me following error

```
Warning: PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in D:\xampp\htdocs\oppInsights\database\Database.php on line 32

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. ' in D:\xampp\htdocs\oppInsights\database\Database.php:39 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\oppInsights\database\Select.php(800): Database->Connection() #1 D:\xampp\htdocs\oppInsights\decision.php(19): Select->expiryContracts() #2 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\oppInsights\database\Database.php on line 39
```

this is the code

```
<?php

class Database {
    public  $dbhost = "mysql:dbname=apt;host=http://10.75.225.171:3601";
    public  $dbuser = "tribhuvan";
    public  $dbpass = "123456";
    public  $dbname = "apt";
    public  $connection;
    public  $selectdb;
    public  $isConnected;
    public  $dbh;

    //$user = 'dbuser';
    //$password = 'dbpass';

    public function Connection()
    {
        try
        {   
             $this->dbh = new PDO($this->dbhost, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass);
            // echo "true";
                return  $this->dbh;
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        { 
                $this->isConnected = false;
                throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public function Disconnect()
    {
        $this->datab = null;
        $this->isConnected = false;
    }
}
?>
```

i have checked username and password they seems to be same as i gave.thank you in advance.

Comment: use ip instead of url in host

Comment: Shouldn't host be without `http://`? -> `host=10.75.255.171:3601` only.

Comment: change $dbhost = "10.75.225.171";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove http from the host and put the port number under port attribute.

Please try with this line :

```
$dbhost = "mysql:host=10.75.225.171;port=3601;dbname=apt";
```